# Android: playing youtube video on Webview

Tags: android, webview, youtube

i've a problem to playing youtube video on a WebView. It's all day i reading question and answer on how to do this, but it doesn't work. **I've already set the Manifest** and this is the code i'm using

```
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });


    mWebview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebview.setInitialScale(1);
    mWebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    //webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    //webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);

    mWebview.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/MYVIDEOID");
```

and what's happen is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZTig.png) i can click the play button the timer start but i can see nothing.

**EDIT:** 
    The problem seems on the emulator and not on real device, check the comment for the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this

```
String frameVideo = "<html><body>Video From YouTube<br><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/47yJ2XCRLZs\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

    WebView displayYoutubeVideo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
    displayYoutubeVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = displayYoutubeVideo.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    displayYoutubeVideo.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

**also set in manifist file** `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

</application>
```

Comment: nothing happen, like before i can click on play button, timer start moving, but cannot see the video

Comment: did you ad this in your application tag     android:hardwareAccelerated="true"'

Comment: load your url like this

Comment: String frameVideo = "<html><body>Video From YouTube<br><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/47yJ2XCRLZs\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

Comment: nothing happen, like the image on the question i see a white block inside the player.

Comment: @justo give your video url

Comment: @justo try with my given video url its working fine in my device

Comment: and make sure your phone has internet connection

Comment: i've used your URL, maybe it's an emulator problem and not happen on real device?

Comment: yup beacuse i checked it on real device and its working

Comment: alright, the problem it's the emulator that can't show correctly the video! damn! Thanks for helping and support me @nilesh!