# Android: Youtube video not available

Tags: android, webview, youtube

We have some YouTube videos that we show in the webview.
For some reason, one of the video is coming as unavailable while it is playing on desktop.

Working URL format: https://youtu.be/watch?v=XXXXX

YouTubeURL format: https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXX

XML:

```
<WebView
     android:id="@+id/video"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="200dp"
     android:contentDescription="YOUTUBE VIDEO TEXT TO READ DURING TALKBACK"
     android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
     android:setYouTubeUrl="@{YouTubeURL}"
     app:ignore="WebViewLayout" />
```

Java:

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:setYouTubeUrl"})
    public static void setYouTubeUrl(WebView webView, String url) {
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // required to view video
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167125/android-playing-youtube-video-on-webview  This seems similar

Comment: That did not worked for me. I get blank screen with the HTML page that they load in webview